# Enable CORS in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have client and a server running on different ports. The server is running **Web API 2 (v5.0.0-rc1)**.

I tried installing the [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Cross-Origin Support package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/) and enabled it in `WebApiConfig.cs`. It gives me the `EnableCors()` function, so the package was installed correctly.

Here you can see my `Register()` function in `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
}
```

`GET` requests work fine. But when sending `POST`, I get the following:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:19357/api/v1/rooms? 404 (Not Found) angular.js:10159
OPTIONS http://localhost:19357/api/v1/rooms? Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. angular.js:10159
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:19357/api/v1/rooms. Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

According to Fiddler it only sends the `OPTIONS` request. It doesn't issue the `POST` afterwards.

So I'm guessing the `config.EnableCors(cors);` in the `WebApiConfig.cs` isn't doing anything, which leads to the server denying the client/browser to send a `POST` request.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

**EDIT 05.09.13** 
This has been fixed in 5.0.0-rtm-130905

Comment: Thanks for the question and answer that it's been fixed in 5.0.0-rtm. Where can I get the RTM version?

Comment: `Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings` and add the following URL under `Package Sources`:
http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm most definitely hitting [this issue](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/954) with attribute routing. [The issue](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/954) was [fixed](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/6eb7f13ca6158800a18dcb299dca481277513cbd) as of 5.0.0-rtm-130905. But still, you can try out the [nightly builds](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds) which will most certainly have the fix.

To add nightlies to your NuGet package source, go to `Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings` and add the following URL under `Package Sources`: http://myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly

Answer (score 84):

CORS works absolutely fine in `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` version 5.2.2. The following steps configured CORS like a charm for me:

1. `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -Version "5.2.2"` // run from Package manager console
2. In Global.asax, add the following line: **BEFORE ANY MVC ROUTE REGISTRATIONS**

   ```
   GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
   ```
3. In the `WebApiConfig` Register method, have the following code:

   ```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
       config.EnableCors();
       config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
   }
   ```

In the web.config, the following handler must be the first one in the pipeline:

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

In the controller derived from `ApiController`, add the `EnableCorsAttribute`:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] // tune to your needs
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class MyController : ApiController
```

That should set you up nicely!

Comment: Like I said it was fixed in 5.0.0-rtm-130905 :)

Comment: Sure, I just added the steps for completeness :)

Comment: Just wanted to add, I wanted CORS enabled, but only at the controller\Action level. I didn't want it open globally. But nothing worked until I added just the config.EnableCors() in the WebApiConfig.... Basically enable it but with 0 params. But then it let me use [System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] at the individual Controller\Action levels.

Comment: how can we do this with .net 4.6.2 ?

Comment: I am using ajax call to web api 2  and I am using same above code in web api project which is running in my local. seen it is not working.

Comment: @user7125929 could you please elaborate on what is not working?

Comment: If you want to apply globally, you can put config.EnableCors("\*","\*","\*"); in WebApiConfig and then not need the declaration at Controller. Also web.config setting it is very much required for it to work (I just got that error :)).

Comment: don't forget to add  
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

Comment: I had to remove ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 before adding it again. So this worked for me - 
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

Answer (score 66):

I didn't need to install any package. Just a simple change in your WebAPI project's web.config is working great:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Credit goes to: [Using CORS in ASP.NET WebAPI Without Being a Rocket Scientist](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617892/Using-CORS-in-ASP-NET-WebAPI-Without-Being-a-Rocke)

Comment: That does the trick, but it does not work if you want to specify CORS on a controller/route basis.

Comment: As you are suggesting the same trick i used for my project, +1! And hate the nuget package, its completely unnecessary !Happy Coding bro!

Comment: Here's another caveat for this approach: With OWIN/Katana, you may not be hosting in IIS, in which case, there's no web.config - That's why the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package is the way to go.

Comment: Another downside of this approach is it causes the header to be included in _every_ response from your server. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors knows to include it only when the request contains the Origin: header.

Comment: It seems the simplest, but doesn't always work, like all cors approaches.

Answer (score 11):

For reference using the `[EnableCors()]` approach will not work if you intercept the Message Pipeline using a `DelegatingHandler`. In my case was checking for an `Authorization` header in the request and handling it accordingly before the routing was even invoked, which meant my request was getting processed earlier in the pipeline so the `[EnableCors()]` had no effect.

In the end found an example [`CrossDomainHandler` class](https://gist.github.com/shaunxu/8414a78cd8074432fc69) *(credit to [shaunxu](https://gist.github.com/shaunxu) for the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/))* which handles the CORS for me in the pipeline and to use it is as simple as adding another message handler to the pipeline.

```
public class CrossDomainHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        const string Origin = "Origin";
        const string AccessControlRequestMethod = "Access-Control-Request-Method";
        const string AccessControlRequestHeaders = "Access-Control-Request-Headers";
        const string AccessControlAllowOrigin = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin";
        const string AccessControlAllowMethods = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods";
        const string AccessControlAllowHeaders = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers";

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            bool isCorsRequest = request.Headers.Contains(Origin);
            bool isPreflightRequest = request.Method == HttpMethod.Options;
            if (isCorsRequest)
            {
                if (isPreflightRequest)
                {
                    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());

                        string accessControlRequestMethod = request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestMethod).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (accessControlRequestMethod != null)
                        {
                            response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowMethods, accessControlRequestMethod);
                        }

                        string requestedHeaders = string.Join(", ", request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestHeaders));
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedHeaders))
                        {
                            response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, requestedHeaders);
                        }

                        return response;
                    }, cancellationToken);
                }
                else
                {
                    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage resp = t.Result;
                        resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());
                        return resp;
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

To use it add it to the list of registered message handlers

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CrossDomainHandler());
```

Any preflight requests by the Browser are handled and passed on, meaning I didn't need to implement an `[HttpOptions]` `IHttpActionResult` method on the Controller.

Comment: This put me onto an issue I was having with ASP .NET Web API CORS policies where the relevant responses don't kick come back. Turns out it is a FilterAttribute based implementation and doesn't participate as early as the ```DelegatingHandler``` phase of the pipeline. So if a handler returns early, you'd have to provide a CORS header response manually (and as per your policies).

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you are accessing the WebAPI through HTTPS.

I also enabled cors in the WebApi.config.

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

But my CORS request did not work until I used HTTPS urls.

Answer (score 6):

This solved my issue:

in Web.config>>Inside system.webServer tags:

```
 <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

And uncomment or delete this line inside system.webServer:

```
<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
```

Also, you need to declare enable cors either in webapiconfig.cs or in web.config. If you declare in both you may get an error something like :

```
'....origin 'www.example.com' blocked by cors policy due to multiple No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'('*','*').'
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

Late reply for future reference. What was working for me was enabling it by nuget and then adding custom headers into web.config.

Comment: Thanks! Installing via the package manage console just wasn't working for me, so I tried it via NuGet interface and it updated the project references automatically and works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
 config.EnableCors(cors);

 var constraints = new {httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Options)};
 config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("OPTIONS", "*pathInfo",constraints);
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable CORS, 
1.Go to App_Start folder.
2.add the namespace 'using System.Web.Http.Cors';
3.Open the WebApiConfig.cs file and type the following in a static method.

```html
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("https://localhost:44328",headers:"*", methods:"*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, the server got to have a header that specifies that Access from Origin is Allowed i.e. a request from the same server could be responded to.
I used the following code :

```
// create a response object of your choice
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

//add the header
//replace the star with a specific name if you want to restrict access
response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

//now you could send the response and it should work...
return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me,

App_Start -> WebApiConfig

```
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("\*", "\*", "GET,HEAD,POST");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```