# Angular 2, Http and Not setting Content-Type "application/json"

Tags: angular, http-headers

I am trying to do a simple Check Login method using Angular 2(2.0.0-rc.1) in a service.  When I attempt to set the content-type to application/json it never sets the headers when sending to my web api backend.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs, RequestMethod, Request, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Other Modules Left out for Security } from 'Hidden';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

private _http: Http;


constructor(http: Http) {
    this._http = http;


}

CheckLogin(model: CredentialModel) {

    let url = 'http://localhost:51671/api/Login';

    let data = JSON.stringify(model);        

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');


    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        url: url,
        headers: headers,
        body: data
    });


    console.log(requestOptions);
    console.log(data);

return this._http.post(url, data, requestOptions);

   }
}
```

#### Request from Web Api

```
OPTIONS /api/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:51671
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:5616
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2754.0 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:5616/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Using the exact same data using PostMan works fine!  Looks like there is an issue with Angular 2 sending application/json using the POST method.

Any help resolving this issue would be helpful.  Open to trying any suggestions.

Comment: Can you try it without requestOptions please? i.e `return this._http.post(url, data, {headers: headers});`

Comment: This is how I do it: `this._http.post(url, body, { headers })` (haha, echonax :D)

Comment: Might be https://github.com/angular/http/issues/71

Comment: You have to allow CORS requests, [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36002699/3125880), or search for `preflight request`, `angular2 cors`

Comment: I've tried each step here and still getting the same error.  For those of you who have it working are you using the latest Angular2 RC1?

Comment: @WannaBDeveloper have you tried enabling CORS on your backend? because from your question, I see the request is `OPTION` not `POST` which is a preflight request that is not meant to have a `content-type` of `application/json`. Please take a look at [this page](http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html) for instructions. Also, check Thierry's answer for the correct way of setting request options.

Comment: The issue was resolved with CORS on the IIS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `post` method of the `Http` class accepts an object of type `RequestOptionsArgs` and not `RequestOptions`.

```
class RequestOptionsArgs {
  url : string
  method : string | RequestMethod
  search : string | URLSearchParams
  headers : Headers
  body : any
  withCredentials : boolean
}
```

You can specify it literally this way within the third parameter:

```
return this._http.post(url, data, { headers: headers });
```

Comment: Was that changed in never angular 2 versions, because RequestOptions works now in my code!

Comment: Just remember to import { Headers }

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Headers in Angular 4 and greater should be set like this now:

let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    });

this.http.post("apiUrl", data, {headers: this.headers})

Answer (score 0):

`RequestOptionsArgs` is an interface in Angular2, so you can specify `RequestOptions` as a value.