# Posted object with collection does not get bound to http body content

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I am doing a http put method to the server sending an object with a list of PupilsScores.

The TestId is bound, but the PupilsScores collection is null.

I also tried `[FromBody]` but that should be the default I assume doing a post/put.

So why is my PupilsScores collection null?

**CLIENT**

```
     updateTestAssignment(pupilsScores, testId) {
   return this.http.put('/api/testassignments/' + testId, { pupilsScores: pupilsScores }).map(res => res.json());
      }
```

**SERVER**

```
public class UpdateTestAssignmentRequestDto
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<PupilsScoresRequestDto> PupilsScores { get; set; }
}

[HttpPut("~/api/testassignments/{testId:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(UpdateTestAssignmentRequestDto dto)
{

    return NoContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `Content-Type` too. Its default value is `text/plain`.

```
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // for ASP.NET MVC
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(product), options).map(....)
```

Comment: Are you sure about RequestOptions? => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595980/angular-2-http-and-not-setting-content-type-application-json , anyway I tried both options and it does not work. JSON stringify is not needed anymore for the last angular 2 releases when content-type is json.

Comment: Ok the mix of setting [FromBody] explicitly AND no json.stringify AND no RequestOptions but following this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595980/angular-2-http-and-not-setting-content-type-application-json made it finally WORK. I also had to put the TestId from the route also again into the payload to get bound with the FromBody.

Comment: `RequestOptions` is mentioned here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Comment: I tested it now with RequestOptions too and it worked too. Thus please change your answer including my findings server/client side :-) thanks!