# Post Request working in Postman but returns Preflight error in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, yii2, postman

THis is the error log from browser console
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain.com/xx/xxxxxxxx. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

This is the expected response as received in Postman

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "code": "E012",
  "message": "Contact sent"
}
```

this is the request made from Angular 2

```
makeRequest(name, recipient) {
let body = JSON.stringify({
  "name": name,
  "recipient": recipient
});

let authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
console.log(authToken);
let headers = new Headers({'Authorization': authToken , 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); 
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
return this.http.post(url, body, options )
  .map(res => res.json());
```

}

Here is the behaviors function in Yii2

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

   // remove authentication filter
    $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

   // add CORS filter
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            // restrict access to
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            // Allow only POST and PUT methods
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            // Allow only headers 'X-Wsse'
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
            // Allow OPTIONS caching
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
            // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => [],
        ],
    ];

   // re-add authentication filter
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
    // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
    $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];

   return $behaviors;
}
```

Here is my UrlManager

```
   'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'POST <version:[\w-]+>/sms' => '<version>/sms/send',
            'POST <version:[\w-]+>/users/verify' => '<version>/user/verify', 
            'POST <version:[\w-]+>/bulk' => '<version>/routine/index',
            'POST <version:[\w-]+>/contact' => '<version>/contact/index'],
```

Comment: remove JSON.stringify from body

Comment: @Akanksha Thanks, but this doesn't Solve the Preflight error I am having

Comment: In Postman you are choosing to send a POST request. a real browser doesn't work that way. an OPTIONS request should be first sent to check if POST is allowed. I guess that is the failing one. could you show the content of your php controller's `behaviors()` function ? and which parent controller are you extending ? is it ActiveController ?

Comment: your service needs to support Options request. You can google how to resolve `CORS` for the language and framework you are using for your backend.

Comment: @SalemOuerdani I have edited my Question to show the behaviors function. I also extended the Controller Class in the Base Controller

Comment: you mean you are directly extending `yii\rest\Controller` instead of `yii\rest\ActiveController`? your filters looks correct to me could you also show how your UrlRules are configured? if extending `yii\rest\Controller` rules to OPTIONS request should be manually added

Comment: @SalemOuerdani Yes I am extending   `yii\rest\Controller`    'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'POST <version:[\w-]+>/users/verify' => '<version>/user/verify',
                'POST <version:[\w-]+>/airtime' => '<version>/airtime/airtime',
                'POST <version:[\w-]+>/bulk' => '<version>/routine/index',
                'POST <version:[\w-]+>/contact' => '<version>/contact/index',
],

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In certain cases a browser will automatically perform a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) to check the list of allowed methods or verbs before actually sending the reel one. You can see those within your browser's network tab. I guess in Postman you are directly sending the `POST`  request while the pre-sent `OPTIONS` request should be the failing one.

Yii has a [built-in action](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/38e97c0fa7f6ceebcf106ebdaf6cb9ae75d8680c/framework/rest/OptionsAction.php) which is [defined under the ActiveController class](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/38e97c0fa7f6ceebcf106ebdaf6cb9ae75d8680c/framework/rest/ActiveController.php#L102-L104) to respond to such requests. But in your case you are directly extending its parent controller instead so you'll need to manually define a similar action inside your controllers *(or a parent one to them)* responding to preflight requests:

```
public function actionOptions() 
{
    if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getMethod() !== 'OPTIONS') {
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->setStatusCode(405);
    }

    $allowed_verbs = ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'];
    Yii::$app->getResponse()->getHeaders()->set('Allow', implode(', ', $allowed_verbs));
}
```

Also; as you are not using the [built-in routing mechanism for REST](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html); in your case you'll also need to manually define `rules` to that **Options** action: *(edited version of the code from your comments)*

```
'urlManager' => [ 
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [ 
        'POST <version:[\w-]+>/users/verify' => '<version>/user/verify',
        'POST <version:[\w-]+>/airtime' => '<version>/airtime/airtime',
        'POST <version:[\w-]+>/bulk' => '<version>/routine/index',
        'POST <version:[\w-]+>/contact' => '<version>/contact/index',

        // OPTTIONS URI ENDPOINTS
        'OPTIONS <version:[\w-]+>/users/verify' => '<version>/user/options',
        'OPTIONS <version:[\w-]+>/airtime' => '<version>/airtime/options',
        'OPTIONS <version:[\w-]+>/bulk' => '<version>/routine/options',
        'OPTIONS <version:[\w-]+>/contact' => '<version>/contact/options',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

You should send body without `JSON.stringify` :

```
let body = {
  "name": name,
  "recipient": recipient
};
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't Solve the Preflight error I am having

Comment: Are you sure 'url' value is current ?

Comment: Yes, It is the same Url I used in postman that I am using in the Web app