# angular 2 Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, typescript

My component file:

```
import { Component , OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http , Response} from '@angular/http';
import { FormGroup , FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({ 

      selector: 'app-banner' ,
      templateUrl:'./banner.component.html' ,

})

export class BannerComponent  
{



    url: string = "http://localhost/demos/items.php";
data = [];
   complexForm : FormGroup;

 constructor(fb: FormBuilder , private http:Http) { 



    this.complexForm = fb.group({
      'firstName' : [null, Validators.required]
    })
  }

  onSubmit(value: any ){

 this.http.post(this.url ,JSON.stringify(value) ).map((res:Response) => res.json() ).subscribe(ans => {
       this.data = ans;
       console.log(this.data);
   });

}

  }
```

In angular2 I got an error like this:

> Failed to load http://localhost/demos/items.php: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response header from the back end web service

for example like this:

```
resp.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
```

and then return the response to the angular client.

more information here:

[origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

[access-control-allow-origin-issue-in-angular-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683195/access-control-allow-origin-issue-in-angular-2)

Comment: this is my simple back end file <?php 
resp.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
return "Hello";
 ?>