# How to add CORS request in header in Angular 5

Tags: angular, cors, angular5

I have added the CORS in header but I am still getting the CORS issue in my request. What is the correct way to add and handle CORS and other requests in the headers?

Here is service file code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Authorization':'authkey',
    'userid':'1'
  })
};

public baseurl = 'http://localhost/XXXXXX';

userAPI(data): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.baseurl, data, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      tap((result) => console.log('result-->',result)),
      catchError(this.handleError('error', []))
    );
}
```

Error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access
>
> failed: Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

In my server-side code, I've added CORS in the index file.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
```

Comment: Need to add the Cors headers on the server side.

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Yes I have added it in my index file.

Comment: post that server file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-xxx-no-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: This answer maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58064366/7059557

Answer (score 57):

In my experience the plugins worked with HTTP but not with the latest httpClient. Also, configuring the CORS response headers on the server wasn't really an option. So, I created a `proxy.conf.json` file to act as a proxy server. This is for development purposes only.

Read more about this [here](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server).

`proxy.conf.json` file:

```
{
  "/posts": {
    "target": "https://example.com",
    "secure": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
    "^/posts": ""
  },
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

I placed the `proxy.conf.json` file right next the the `package.json` file in the same directory.

Then I modified the start command in the package.json file:

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
```

The HTTP call from my app component:

```
return this._http.get('/posts/pictures?method=GetPictures')
.subscribe((returnedStuff) => {
  console.log(returnedStuff);
});
```

Lastly to run my app, I'd have to use `npm start` or `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Comment: It works just for development purposes. You can't build your app with that proxy tool

Comment: Could someone here please have a look at the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429787/proxy-to-multiple-paths-angular?noredirect=1#comment97578761_55429787

Comment: what should we set the `target` as in the proxy.config file?

Comment: i tied it showing status ok but now getting new error. `HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/", ok: false, …} error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) 
message: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
"
`

Comment: this doesn't work in production builds, so it can't be a proper solution

Comment: Some updated link to the setup of the proxy.conf.json file : https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Comment: This doesn't help at all

Answer (score 12):

You can also try the `fetch` function and the `no-cors` mode. I sometimes find it easier to configure it than Angular's built-in http module. You can right-click requests in the Chrome Dev tools network tab and copy them in the fetch syntax, which is great.

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

// ...

result = from( // wrap the fetch in a from if you need an rxjs Observable
  fetch(
    this.baseurl,
    {
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors'
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: The code in the question is trying to *read* the response. `no-cors` blocks that. It also blocks setting the content-type to `application/json`.

Comment: Very specific case, for https://api.github.com/orgs/nesign/repos, I saw `Access to XMLHttpRequest at '..' from origin '..' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-timezone is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` unable to override `Access-Control-Request-Headers: cache-control,x-timezone` which got added by default  :( and Github has this in response `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Accept-Encoding, X-GitHub-OTP, X-Requested-With, User-Agent` fetch worked

Comment: Oops! x-timezone was added by me - I had _over engineered_ the `httpclient` with an interceptor long time back :)

Comment: Thank you for the mode parameter. I have an app that sends an api request to a local computer and prints labels. The angular app is in the cloud so using a proxy is not possible because the request has to come from inside the network.

Answer (score 7):

If you are like me and you are using a local SMS Gateway server and you make a GET request to an IP like 192.168.0.xx you will get for sure CORS error.

Unfortunately I could not find an Angular solution, but with the help of a previous replay I got my solution and I am posting an updated version for Angular 7 8 9

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';

getData(): Observable<any> {
    return from(
      fetch(
        'http://xxxxx', // the url you are trying to access
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          method: 'GET', // GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
          mode: 'no-cors' // the most important option
        }
      ));
  }
```

Just .subscribe like the usual.

Comment: Works as expected, I'm using it when changing the protocol of a web application from HTTP to HTTPS to check if the new API is up and then redirect. We have strict CORS/HSTS policy so it doesn't work using a normal GET.

Comment: Also note that fetch doesn't work on IE11

Comment: it really works! without any proxy!

Answer (score 3):

Make the header looks like this for HttpClient in NG5:

```
let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'apikey': this.apikey,
        'appkey': this.appkey,
      }),
      params: new HttpParams().set('program_id', this.program_id)
    };
```

You will be able to make api call with your localhost url, it works for me 
..

- Please never forget your params columnd in the header:
  such as params: new HttpParams().set('program_id', this.program_id)

Answer (score 2):

A POST with httpClient in Angular 6 was also doing an OPTIONS request:

Headers General:

```
Request URL:https://hp-probook/perl-bin/muziek.pl/=/postData
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

My Perl REST server implements the OPTIONS request with return code 200.

The next POST request Header:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:hp-probook
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36
```

Notice Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type.

So, my backend perl script uses the following headers:

```
 -"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => '*',
 -"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" => 'GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS',
 -"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" => 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, content-type',
```

With this setup the GET and POST worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

please import requestoptions from angular cors

```
import {RequestOptions, Request, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

and add request options in your code like given below

```
let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers:null, withCredentials: 
    true });
```

send request option in your api request

code snippet below-

```
 let requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers:null, 
     withCredentials: true });
     return this.http.get(this.config.baseUrl + 
     this.config.getDropDownListForProject, requestOptions)
     .map(res => 
     {
      if(res != null)
      { 
        return res.json();
        //return true;
      }
    })
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

and add CORS in your backend PHP code where all api request will land first.

try this and let me know if it is working or not i had a same issue i was adding CORS from angular5 that was not working then i added CORS to backend and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

add this comment in your API file

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH");
```

I've tried to implement these solutions to add CORS header response to Laravel to my project but I still have not had any success:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors

I'm hoping that someone has encountered a similar issue and can help.

Answer (score -8):

The following worked for me after hours of trying

```
      $http.post("http://localhost:8080/yourresource", parameter, {headers: 
      {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } }).
```

However following code did not work, I am unclear as to why, hopefully someone can improve this answer.

```
          $http({   method: 'POST', url: "http://localhost:8080/yourresource", 
                    parameter, 
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'} 
                })
```

Comment: $http ? Is it AngularJS, because we're talking about Angular 5 there. Couldn't make this code work

Comment: @VictorJozwicki You are correct it is not Angular 5. In my package.json it shows angular version 1.7.5.