# Angular 5 : HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to find help with Angular 5 and its module httpClient, before posting I look several times the doc of angular and various tutorial without success.

I'm trying to pass two informations in a form from a json from a server I created locally.

**What I want:**
Pass my information on my page from the HttpClient component.

**The encountered difficulties**

I have two errors, my first attempts, I correctly recover the JSON file but in my console, I have a 404 error (I specify my server is on and I can see my json at the address I have provided in my component-service.ts).

*My second error since Friday:*

> Cross-Origin Request Blocking: The "Same Origin" policy does not allow
>   viewing of the remote resource located at http: // localhost: 3000 /
>   main.json. Reason: The CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is
>   missing.

I added a Headers object with the 'Access-Control-Allow-origin': '*' property. Angular does not want to know anything, worse looking at the log, he does not show me anything in the header he returns to me…

*main-service.ts*

```
import { Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Main } from '../model/main';


const baseUri = 'http://localhost:3000/';
const jsonDirectory = 'javascripts/';
const main = 'main.json';
const jsonHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'});

@Injectable()
export class MainService implements OnInit {

  mainRequest = baseUri + jsonDirectory + main;

  jsonOption = jsonHeaders;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.getMain());
  }

  getMain(): Observable<Main> {
    return this.http.get<Main>(this.mainRequest, {withCredentials: true, headers: this.jsonOption});
  }

}
```

*main.component.ts*

```
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import { MainService } from '../shared/service/main-service';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})


export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
 @Injectable()

  public id: number;
  public name: string;

  constructor(private mainService: MainService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  mainGroup = this.fb.group({
        id:  [{value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.min(0)],
        name: ['', Validators.minLength(3)]
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMain();
  }

  getMain() {
    this.mainService.getMain()
        .subscribe(data => {this.id = data.id; this.name = data.name; }, err => console.log(err));
  }

  confirmForm() {
    console.log(this.mainGroup);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a CORS issue, try checking this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345282/how-to-add-cors-request-in-header-in-angular-5

Comment: The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must be present in the response headers, not in the request. Check your server that is allowing your front-end address to access server resources. For instance requesting data from http://localhost:4200 (client) to http://localhost:4201 (server) must be allowed by the api.

Comment: or just go wild and disable web-security for your browser :)

Comment: Thank you for all ! I have find a solution with :  https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ or https://github.com/typicode/json-server. for the future viewer.