# my angular 6 get HTTP request with token authorization header isn't working

Tags: angular, laravel, api, authorization, laravel-passport

i am trying to do a get request with angular 6 to an API on a production server and i sent an authorization token header together with it but i keep getting

- XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "http://myserver/api/endpoint"
- OPTIONS "http://myserver/api/endpointnet ::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"
- message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"

Error

```
Here is my code 

authheader = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization':  'Bearer '+this.tokenr,
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    })
  }

 public async getUserInfo() {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.realapi + '/user', this.authheader)
        .map(data => <any>data)
      .subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
        console.log(data, 'data here');
      }, err => {
        console.log(err,'errorrr');
      });
    });
  }
```

I am supposed to use this endpoint to fetch the user details after successful sign in from a laravel(passport) 5.7 api

Below is how i am handling my CORS and Preflight request in laravel

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
class PreflightResponse
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
    * @param \Closure $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next )
    {
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, application/json');
        return $response;
    }
 }
```

I added it to the $protected middleware(so it passes through all the request) in the kernel.php file

Funny enough, the POST http request works but the GET doesn't :(

```
POST request carries the data/parameter and 'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' header but the GET request just using the 'Authorization'; 'Bearer '+token
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: This may be a CORS problem, it happen when you make calls from different domains. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345282/how-to-add-cors-request-in-header-in-angular-5

Comment: @kaosdev yes it is i will share my code real soon

Comment: @MrWhiteNerdy i have done that

Comment: Wich headers do you send back for an options request?

Comment: @kaosdev that was a mistake, removed it already and i still have the same error

Comment: Can you share which headers are sent back from your server when you make an option request?

Comment: @kaosdev  $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=>'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'
        ];