# Proxy to multiple paths angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to proxy to a certain API endpoint that returns an html page but I get the error
`Access to font at 'https://data.domain.com/v3/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

`GET https://data.domain.com/v3/assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 net::ERR_FAILED`

Inside my angular app, I have three different targets that I am proxying to. The first two proxies work fine but the other is a bit weird.
My `proxy.conf.json` file looks sth like this...

```
{
  "/API": {}, // First proxy works fine
  "/info": {}, // Second proxy fine too
  "/data": {
    "target": "https://data.domain.com/v3/uk",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/data": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

So inside my data service, I define a variable `data` that contains the path `'/data'` and I pass that as the path in my POST request like so...

```
private data = '/data';

public fetchData(data: Data) {
  return this.http.post(this.data, data, {responseType: 'text');
}
```

Upon making that post request, I'm expecting the returned value to be some html code that I'd like to bind to my template. Herein lies the problem. You see, the returned HTML looks something like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>My Page</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="https://data.domain.com/v3/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://data.domain.com/v3/assets/css/loading-bar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://data.domain/v3/assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body
        <p class="title">Page Title</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

See that bootstrap import? I think that's what's causing the problem because inside the `bootstrap.min.css` code, references to the `glyphicons-halflings-regular` font are made like so...

`url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2) format('woff2'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff) format('woff'),url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf) format('truetype')`

Hence for each of those font formats, I get the exact same error repeated.
How can I solve this?

Comment: The issue seems to be with the server `https://data.domain.com` which is not allowing request from `localhost`. Hence the cors error. You would be  seeing a `options` request in the network tab. The response headers as you posted clearly say `from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy`. In this case the server needs to allow requests

Comment: Could I just proxy to `https://data.domain.com/*` and maybe that would fix this issue? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: The issue is not with your proxy. It is a security restriction on the server. It needs to allow incoming request from the origin  `http://localhost:4200`. Do you have control over the server ?

Comment: I don't have control over the server.