# RXJS Observable MergeMap Chain

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, cors, observable

I have this simple api request which returns an observable to an object which has a bunch of items in it and in every item there is a link.
So i wanted to directly fetch the data behind the link in my current async stream but i get a CORS error saying:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://orf.at/stories/3146336/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is this even possible with my current `fetchOrfFeed()` function?
Or did I missunderstood some basic concept?

```js
public fetchOrfFeed(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<OrfFeed>('https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://rss.orf.at/news.xml')
      .pipe(mergeMap(feed => feed.items))
      .pipe(mergeMap(item => this.http.get<string>(item.link)));
  }
```

Comment: Your issue is unrelated to RxJS. You need to configure a CORS request, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345282/how-to-add-cors-request-in-header-in-angular-5

Answer (score 1):

You can either configure your proxy or, as commented above, configure your CORS Request.

If you choose the proxy option (I think its better):

Have a look in your **proxy.config.json** file from your Angular project and add that URL to it.

For example:

```
{
    "/api/fetch-or-feed": {
        "target": "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://rss.orf.at/news.xml",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

then use it in your service call like

```
return this.http.get<OrfFeed>('/api/fetch-or-feed')...
```

More info here: [Configure a proxy for your API calls with Angular CLI](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/)

Comment: configuring a proxy server for your dev environment only fixes issues with localhost. it won't fix CORS issues in a deployed app...