# URL work on postman but not using httpclient Angular 9 +

Tags: angular, typescript, postman, httpclient

I am trying to fetch the json data from one URL which works if you paste on browser and also through postman but when I make GET requesting using Angular HttpClietn then getting CORS Policy error.

Can anyone help me to understand why this is not working.

URL : **https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/api/v1/search?key=IDEA**

**Angular Code:**

-- First Attempt

```
  GetScripInfo(): Observable<any>{
    let header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    header.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const requestOptions = {  headers: header};  
   
    return this.httpClient.get<any>("https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/api/v1/search?key=IDEA", 
    requestOptions).pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        debugger;
        res.json()})
    );
  }
```

-- Second Attempt

```
   GetScripInfo(): Observable<any>{
      
        let header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', });
    
        header.set('access-control-allow-origin',"http://localhost:4200/");
        header.set('withCredentials', "true");
        header.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const requestOptions = {  headers: header};  
       
        return this.httpClient.get<any>("https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/api/v1/search?key=IDEA", requestOptions);
      }
```

**Calling Method**

```
GetScripInfo(value: string) {
    debugger;
    this.algoService.GetScripInfo().subscribe(result => {
      debugger;
    });
  }
```

**-- StackBlitz URL --**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rbbwp6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: There might be something wrong with yor headers and requestOptions.
"Accept" and "Content-Type" is "application/json" by default so you could try your `get` without options.
Also, `res.json` should not be needed as it parses the response data by default since a few Angular versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add CORS request in header in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345282/how-to-add-cors-request-in-header-in-angular-5)

Comment: any other suggestions ?