# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present.. angular 7 and express

Tags: node.js, express, angular7, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am running a server with express at port 3000 and a client with angular 7 at port 4200. Once I make a request, I run into CORS issue.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/drug' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have tried all the solutions online like using cors package, and setting the middleware before router like below codes ([Angular 6 - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448981/angular-6-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested)). But it still is not solved and keep getting same errors. Does anyone have same problem that CORS is not solved with all the solutions? Could you please help me?

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Header",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
      res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Header",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
      );
      next();
    });
```

Comment: Add anyone middleware from above code before your API routes initialization.

Comment: @AnnaLee did found the solution?

Comment: Yes,  I have added chrom extension (chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/…), now it is working fine.

Comment: how can we say to our customers to install this chrome extension to run this type of functionality?

Comment: This answer maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58064366/7059557

Answer (score 5):

Put this line of code `app.use(cors());` before routing code. (Assuming you have installed `cors` package).

Comment: Of course, I did, I figure this out just now, I have added chrom extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en), now it is working fine.

Comment: @AnnaLee Thanks Finally found the correct answer.Almost 1 day wasted.

Answer (score 0):

I think answer would be so late, but for somebody in future:
You have to turn it on at the server side.
I'm .Net developer, therefore I'll show in example of .Net core app.
In startup file method `ConfigureServices` you should add next code

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

After that you should edit method `Configure`. Add next line before calling `UseMvc`

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

That's all. I hope this answer will help to somebody.