# How to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin for angular 5/nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angular, http, angular5, webpack-dev-server

Read many ways for including of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and none worked for me.

I use @angular/common/http module and external url as data source.
by the attempt to get data instead, get error:
/////.................

```
Failed to load http://accounts.......com/accounts: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

**account.service.ts:**

```js
import { Injectable                    } from '@angular/core';
import { Router                        } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams        } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders                   } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable                    } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError                    } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Account                       } from '../models/account';

const baseUrl     : string = 'http://accounts..................com/';
const httpOptions : any    = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    //'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  })
};

@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  private isUserLoggedIn;
  private usreName;
  private account : Account;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  logIn (credentials: any): Observable<Account> {
    return this.http.get<Account>(baseUrl + 'accounts');
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule                 } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule              } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule                      } from '@angular/core';

import { routing                       } from './routing';
import { AppComponent                  } from './app.component';
import { AppGlobal                     } from './app.global';

import { AccountComponent              } from './components/account/account.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations  : [
    AppComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    ....
  ],
  imports       : [
    routing,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CookieModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers     : [AccountService, AppGlobal],
  bootstrap     : [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Help please

**////////////////Tried fix 1**

```js
//......
import { HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
//.......
logIn (credentials: any): Observable<Account> {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
      .append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
      .append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return this.http.get<Account>(baseUrl + 'accounts',  {headers});
}
```

[image]

I am still getting that error :

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

**////////////////Tried fix 2**

proxy.conf.json:

```js
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:4200",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

also error

Comment: CORS should be enabled by the server from which you are requesting the resource, not from Angular.

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta, Angular2+ is client library and it's not used for server side rendering. I use only, I suppose webpack-dev-server should be configurated

Comment: No, webpack does not need to be configured for CORS. Angular i snot a client library, it is a Framework. See Ab Ebube's answer below. As you can see, he is configuring cors server side NOT client side

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta, I use node js also, didn't think that node js should be configurated

Comment: Any server you use needs to be configured. If you are using NodeJS server, then you can use the npm package called CORS which lets you configure it pretty easily

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta, I npm installed ember-cli-cors, it's not worked for me.

Comment: That's not the one. use this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors. Once you install it, you'll basically need to tell nodejs this with CORS options: "Hey NodeJS, please accept any request from http://localhost:4200". After that, you should be good to go

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta, Is there some config instruction for angular/typescript?

Comment: This answer maybe useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58064366/7059557

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Set headers to allow CORS origin in Express **

=> Add code in the server.js file or mail file.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
 });
```

CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is an HTML5 feature that allows one site to access another site’s resources despite being under different domain names.

The W3C specification for CORS actually does a pretty good job of providing some simple examples of the response headers, such as the key header, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, and other headers that you must use to enable CORS on your web server.

Comment: I don't use ExpressJs

Comment: You have to enable CORS on the API Server (Where API Developed).  On which server API developed?

Comment: I got API from unknow server for me. I just need to use it

Comment: I can get/see data from direct link API, but not via Angular

Comment: You have to tell API developer to enable CORS. Happy coding

Comment: Great, Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET Api then add this to your WebApiConfig.cs file

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*",
                                           "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                                           "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to install nuget packet Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors for this

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned webpack-dev-server, which of course can handle CORS since it's using express behind the scenes. In your webpack config

```
devServer: {
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Is response header not request header. You must add this header to your resfull (server)

Comment: This took me like two months to understand that it is not a certain browser's feature to block the cors request but the server's configuration