# Angular 2 - Chrome and IE(11) CORS issue

Tags: angular

I am running angular 2 app(using angular-cli) and making a server API call(where CORS access for all(*) is implemented within the API code).

Now, when i am trying to make an API call from the angular 2 app,sometime i am getting the response from the server with no CORS issues at all and sometime i am getting below issue:

For Chrome browser:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://server.com/api/currency.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

For IE(11) browser

```
SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:4200 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
File: localhost:4200
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
File: localhost:4200
```

For both the above browser the the response header returns

```
Response : HTTP/1.1 500 Interenal Server Error
Content-Length : 0
```

I also tried clearing the browser cache,but it's not working as expected and am getting above issue again.

Any help with above would be really appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: It seems to me that the [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002493/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-angular-2-app) was many times.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I'm using OSX El Capitan 10.11.6, Chrome 58.0.3029.96. The problem doesn't happen on Safari.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your backend. You are receiving a message that `the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`, it means that some exception has occured there and that's why no proper headers were set to the response.

Check apache logs to find out what's happening there.