# Angular2 Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, http, typescript, post, postman

I was trying to make a simple POST request to create an account with API in .NET, but it fails with warning as the title says. 
Doing the same request in Postman(api testing tool) returns status 200: OK, everything works fine this way and data got saved to the database.
But I cant do the same in my web application, this is my code:

```
  register(){

let details = {
  Serviceurl: this.serviceUrl,
  CompanyName: this.companyName,
  CompanyFullName: this.companyFullName,
  LanguageCulture: this.languageCulture,
  IsNewUser: this.isNewUser,
  User: {
    UserName: this.userName,
    FirstName: this.firstName,
    LastName: this.lastName,
    Email: this.email,
    Password: Md5.hashStr(this.password)
  }
}

this.authService.createAccount(details)
.then((result) => {

}, (err) => {

});
}
```

and then the request itself in my authService:

```
  createAccount(details){

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('http://SITEADDRESS/api/IM_Customers/CreateNew', JSON.stringify(details), {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {
        let data = res.json();
        resolve(data);

      }, (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });

});
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to Google it? It's caused by the CORS policy of browsers. Postman doesn't require it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#section_5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in Angular 2 app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002493/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-angular-2-app)

Comment: yeah i tried solving it with google, and i thought i have this enabled and something is wrong with my client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin in API project.
In API Project, startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
    app.UseCors(builder=>builder.AllowOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
}
```