# WebApi2 Cross-Origin Request Blocked from Angular Front End

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-web-api2, angular6

Angular WebApp:

```
http://localhost:57729/ 
VS 2017, Core 2.1
```

API:

```
http://localhost:3554
VS 2017, .Net 4.6
```

I am getting into cors issue, have been implementing different solutions and so far no success. No authentication is happening in this case. I have test API controller and it has a get method which is returning OK response.

Directly executing a test `http://localhost:3554/MWAPI/Test` gives me this result

[image]

When I try to run it from Angular web app, I am getting into the following cors issue

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3554/MWAPI/test. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘(null)’).`

I have gone through multiple resources and it still isn't working for me.

[Enable CORS in Web API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619656/enable-cors-in-web-api-2)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617892/Using-CORS-in-ASP-NET-WebAPI-Without-Being-a-Rocke

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3173363/application-development/how-to-enable-cors-on-your-web-api.html

Here is what i have now...

Web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>  
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    //url is without the trailing slash
    //var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:57729", "*", "*");
    var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "http://localhost:57729", headers: "*", methods: "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);

    var constraints = new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Options) };
    config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("OPTIONS", "*pathInfo", constraints);

    //testing... or remove all formats 
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();

    //testing... and add indenting and camel case if we need
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "MWAPI/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "MWAPI/{controller}/{action}");
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "MWAPI/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "MWAPI/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });       
}
```

Checked API with the following and no issue connecting

1. Telerik Fiddler
2. created a quick WinForms application and called the get/post/delete/put methods via HttpClient and async methods. No issue here.

I am missing something else over here and now can't pinpoint. Do you see anything that I may be missing here?

**Update 1:**

and here is the call from front end

app.component test function

```
handleSomeTests() {
    let api = "test"

    //standard get,returns HttpStatusCode.OK, "Standard Get executed"
    console.log("===Standard Get===");
    this.dataService.get<any>(api +'').subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      error => {
        //error.message, error.name, error.ok, error.status, error.statusText, error.url
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

and the data service (not complete yet but doing its basic job)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry  } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  baseApi: string = 'MWAPI';
  baseUrl: string = 'http://localhost:3554/';
  retries: number = 0;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * A GET method
   * @param url api url without leading / and MWAPI/ as well
   * @param params pass empty, will cover stuff like ?x=1&y=2, instead use HttpParams  pass as { params: { sessionTimeOut: 'y' } } or const params = new HttpParams().set('q', 'cironunes');
   * @returns returns T string/number/model
   */
  get<T>(url: string, params: any | null = null): Observable<T> {
    url = `${this.baseUrl}${this.baseApi}/${url}`;
    return this.http
      .get<T>(url, { params })
      .pipe(retry(this.retries));
  }

  /**
   * A POST method
   * @param url api url without leading / and MWAPI/ as well
   * @param body model posting
   * @param params pass empty, will cover stuff like ?x=1&y=2, instead use HttpParams  pass as { params: { sessionTimeOut: 'y' } } or const params = new HttpParams().set('q', 'cironunes');
   * @returns returns T string/number/model
   */
  post<T>(url: string, body, params: any | null = null): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    url = `${this.baseUrl}${this.baseApi}/${url}`;
    return this.http
      .post<T>(url, body, params)
      .pipe(retry(this.retries));
  }

  /**
   * A PUT method
   * @param url  api url without leading / and MWAPI/ as well
   * @param body model posting
   * @param params pass empty, will cover stuff like ?x=1&y=2, instead use HttpParams  pass as { params: { sessionTimeOut: 'y' } } or const params = new HttpParams().set('q', 'cironunes');
   * @returns returns T string/number/model
   */
  put<T>(url: string, body, params: any | null = null): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    url = `${this.baseUrl}${this.baseApi}/${url}`;
    return this.http
      .put<T>(url, body, params)
      .pipe(retry(this.retries));
  }

  /**
   * A DELETE method
   * @param url  api url without leading / and MWAPI/ as well
   */
  delete(url: string): Observable<object> {
    url = `${this.baseUrl}${this.baseApi}/${url}`;
    return this.http
      .delete(url)
      .pipe(retry(this.retries));
  }

}
```

**Update 2:**

Full error response

```
{…}​error: error​​
bubbles: false​​
cancelBubble: false
​​cancelable: false​​
composed: false​​
currentTarget: null
​​defaultPrevented: false
​​eventPhase: 0​​
explicitOriginalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:3554/MWAPI/test", readyState: 4, … }​​
isTrusted: true​​
lengthComputable: false​​
loaded: 0​​
originalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:3554/MWAPI/test", readyState: 4, … }​​target: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:3554/MWAPI/test", readyState: 4, … }​​
timeStamp: 88583​​total: 0​​type: "error"​​<prototype>: ProgressEventPrototype { lengthComputable: Getter, loaded: Getter, total: Getter, … }
​headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
​message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
​name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​ok: false
​status: 0​
statusText: "Unknown Error"​
url: null​
<prototype>: Object { constructor: HttpErrorResponse() } app.component.ts:81:8
```

**Update 3:**

chrome is also showing

```
Failed to load http://localhost:3554/MWAPI/test: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:57729' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I changed to following, using url instead of * for origins

```
var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "http://localhost:57729", headers: "*", methods: "*")
```

and now chrome is showing this error

```
Failed to load http://localhost:3554/MWAPI/test: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:57729, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:57729' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Where is it not liking the allow origin?

I have also tested by doing following and still the same result.

- only kept the web.config and commented registration code
- commented web.config and kept the registration code

**Update 4: Working Solution**
@VishalAnand comment and chrome helped fix the issue.

1. Removed following from the web.config
2. Removed constraints from the webapiconfig register method, left only the first two lines.

   ```
   var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*");
   config.EnableCors(cors);

   //var constraints = new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Options) };
   //config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("OPTIONS", "*pathInfo", constraints);
   ```

It is working for the get method. I haven't tested put/post/delete, hopefully these will work as well.

Comment: var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "http://localhost:57729", headers: "*", methods: "*"); Check the port number if it's correct

Comment: Port is correct. Even changed it to `var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*");` and still the same result.

Comment: have you looked at it https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182478/configure-access-control-allow-origin-for-clients-with-origin-null ?

Comment: also, can you post response of your OPTIONS request?

Comment: also a wild guess, can you try out by removing  config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("OPTIONS", "*pathInfo", constraints);

Comment: Tried it without constrains. Still the same issue. I have also placed Update 2 in the question, it has the full error response.

Comment: Posted update 3 in the question, plz take a look...

Comment: @VishalAnand plz put your comment regarding removing ignore routes as an answer and i'll accept it. Along with this, i also needed to remove web.config entries. The only thing remaining in WebApiConfig register method is `var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing config.Routes.IgnoreRoute("OPTIONS", "*pathInfo", constraints); and it should work.

Comment: Also removed we.config entries. Plz see update 4 for more details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `EnableCors` attribute for controller

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.site.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I have done (with origins as * and url)  this along with the solution implemented in my question. I haven't tested this alone though.

Comment: tested it alone also. Same result. Chrome is giving one extra piece, plz see update 3 in the question.