# CORS issue in Angular 6, while calling the API

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, angular6

Access to fetch at 'http://URL' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I got the above error in console .But I have enabled the CORS in WEB API other API  requests are not showing this error.

service :

```
 ViewPDF(mMagazineId){
    return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + `/api/ViewPDF/?mMagazineId=${mMagazineId}`);
  }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
 config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
```

I am really confused with this issue .Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: I had a similar issue and what solved it was by changing the configuration at the Web Server (Tomcat in my case).

Comment: You're configuring it improperly. Just read Microsoft's help pages and other resources like this: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619656/enable-cors-in-web-api-2).

Answer (score 0):

You should change server properties for allow to CORS if you can.
[How to do it.](https://enable-cors.org/server.html)

If you dont have access to change server properties you could try call api with JSONP. Its not easy as JSON call. I have tried it but server didnt let me to do that too.

Answer (score 0):

Check the backend entity property and json model passed from angular they are  equal  even the case it matters.