# When I deploy the Blazor WebAssembly, API stops responding

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly, plesk

Application = Blazor Web Assembly PWA Framework 6.0

API = Rest Api .netcore Framework 5.0

WEB Address = localtesting.mydomain.com

API Address = (localtesting.mydomain.com/api) Virtual directory.

I created virtual directory and uploaded my API in virtual directory.
APi Works fine as expected

Then i try to upload Blazor WASM on root folder but when i do so API stops working. As wasm is redirecting URL.

I think its due to fallout rule from blazor which is handled by web.config

i tried to edit web.config but cant get it to work

so i am tryig to add a rule in web.config to not intercept requests for API.

[image: api response when Blazor WebAssembly is not published]
[image: on Plesk There is no one here but Awhen upload Blazor WebAssemblyPI]
[image: when uploading Blazor WebAssembly]

[image: No data when]

i have tried to edit web.config but still cant get it to work
as blazor redirects all requests to wwwroot folder

Following is the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

    enter code here
```

Comment: Maybe the endpoint of the api is on the same por as the blazor app?

Comment: How can I set the endpoint  in Blzor WebAssembly there is no Startup.cs file like in Blazor Server

Comment: First you need to check if the two projects are deployed to different ports or if they are deployed to the same port.

Comment: sorry @hesolar that was the not problem. If I upload Blazor server-side API responds correctly. The problem is only in Blazor WebAssembly.When I upload Blazor API doesn't respond.

Comment: Looks like you need to enable CORS policy. similar here: [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619656/enable-cors-in-web-api-2)

Comment: @HenkHolterman i have edited the question. can you please let me know which iis configration do u think may be causing this issue

Comment: @DrewAguirre follwing is my CORS policy            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

Comment: 405 means method not allowed.. maybe you need to check your HTTPverb, for example you are using a POST api call on a GET endpoint..

Comment: The wasm is expected to be served from www folder of the application by default. Web.config is connected with IIS and has nothing to do with your blazor app. How is the API configured? did you by any chance overwrite any files regarding the API when moving the wasm files to root folder?

Comment: @DrewAguirre my HTTPverb is correct because if I request a API before uploading Blazor WebAssembly, app responds correctly whenever upload  Blazor WebAssembly and after send the request then error comes like 405 or etc.

Comment: Thanks, @HenkHolterman this is useful info but I need some more

Comment: @H.M.Mubashir on properties folder, launchsettings.json file you can set the starting url

Answer (score 2):

by adding the following code in the config.Proj file

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
</location>
```